# jQuery / CSS - Full width background image when scrolling down to only stick a half of image fixed on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I would like to achieve is is that when I scroll down the screen with a full width image and a height of 450px, is to keep half of the background image fixed on top of the screen and then the picture will go back to its initial state as I scroll back up at a certain point. I am also using sticky.js plugin to help me.

Here is the code that I have tried with jQuery:

```
$('.category-banner').sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.category-banner'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 300) $('.category-banner').css('position', 'fixed')
  else if (scroll <=  300)$('.category-banner').css('position', 'relative')
});
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.category-banner {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-image: url('/assets/img/categorybanner.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 450px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Right now the result is that when I scroll down at a given point, the full width and height of the background image is fixed, what I wanted is only half of the image is sticking to the top as I scroll down at a specific point and go back to its initial full width and height when I reach back on top of the page.

Please also note that I am trying to achieve this with a css background image. Thank you!

Comment: From what I understand, without using multiple backgrounds on the same element which would get complex, you will need to have 2 separate elements for each half of your image, using background-size and background-position to show the right bit of each

Comment: Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ep3rnuhy/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef you should add this as an answer, looks like a good solution. I would get rid of the transitions though. It's a good idea, but doesn't quite look right

Comment: Looks great and just what I need, except that I am trying to achieve this with a css background image.